# Simple bot in ruby

Tags: ruby, browser, bots, posting

I have written some simple bot in ruby (watir)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver' 

Watir::Browser.default = "firefox"
browser = Watir::Browser.start "http://example.com/"
browser.link(:text, "microblog").click
browser.area(:name, "body").set("test post")
browser.button(:value,"Send").click
```

how can I achieve something like this, but without browser window (full in console)?
can you link me some tutorials or something?

Comment: It sounds like you want something like [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your pages are not heavily dependent on JavaScript, [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) may be sufficient.

You can find some examples here:

http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/GUIDE_rdoc.html
http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html